# Can't get Json data using http request

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get `share_count` data for page `https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://backlinko.com` 
Here my code:

```html
<div id='demo'/>
<script>
  var fbsrc = "https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://universalmanual.com";
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', fbsrc, true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    // Success!
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    document.getElementByID('demo').innerHTML+=data.share.share_count;
  } 
};



request.send();
</script>
```

Comment: I think you miss some authentication in the request header.

Comment: `TypeError: document.getElementByID is not a function` if that's the only problem, then should be closed for `a simple typo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call seems to work fine and the output is coming. You have a typo-

```
document.getElementByID('demo').innerHTML+=data.share.share_count;
```

It should be

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML+=data.share.share_count;
```

Also the response is coming in below json format -

```
{
   "http://universalmanual.com": {
      "share": {
         "comment_count": 0,
         "share_count": 0
      },
      "og_object": {
         "id": "477708298951135",
         "type": "website",
         "updated_time": "2013-04-02T05:16:14+0000"
      },
      "id": "http://universalmanual.com"
   }
}
```

So share count is available in

```
data["http://universalmanual.com"].share.share_count
```

Updated codepen -  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oqowZN

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the typo in `document.getElementById` you also need to correct how you are accessing the `share_count`. You need to access it as `data['http://universalmanual.com'].share.share_count`

```html
<div id='demo'/>
<script>
  var fbsrc = "https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://universalmanual.com";
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', fbsrc, true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    // Success!
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML+=data['http://universalmanual.com'].share.share_count;
  } 
};



request.send();
</script>
```